# Blank screen for canvas app

Tags: facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I followed this tutorial [Gath Adams Tutorial:How to write a facebook application in 10 min](http://gathadams.com/2007/06/18/how-to-write-a-facebook-application-in-10-minutes/)

I could tell from that it was a bit outdated from seeing how only 50% or so of the field names matched what I could see on my end as I was trying to make this demo app, but I changed things as I thought necessary. Here's a shot of what my fields look like:*
*Nevermind, apparently as a new poster, I can't post images. I'll list out the main fields:

Namespace: gathguessgame

Canvas URL: http://[pseudoDomainName]/guessdemo/

Secure Canvas URL: https://[pseudoDomainName]/guessdemo/

Canvas Page: http://apps.facebook.com/gathguessgame

The only files in the guessdemo directory of my webserver are a temp "Terms of Service" (htm), a temp "Privacy Policy" (htm), and a copy of the tutorial's simple game code ("guess.htm"). It seemed simple enough to get this demo app working for the tutorial's author, but when I go to the canvas page url, I just get a blank canvas. What other basic components might be new and not included in this tutorial would I need to get this demo app working in facebook? I appreciate any help you guys could give me!

What I've tried:

- making sure that the website handles all verbs (https://www.supportsages.com/http-405-the-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed/)

Comment: What I am getting when looking at your canvas page is _“The connection has timed out. The server at 50.18.185.198 is taking too long to respond.”_ And when I try to access `https://50.18.185.198/guessdemo/`directly, same thing. When trying to access it non-secure over HTTP only, I get an 200 OK response code and a content-length of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was most likely an issue of permissions, but I never got it to work on its own (might've been something to do with using a Windows server). Anyway, my co-worker tried a different Linux server and got it to run fine. Thanks for the feedback still, CBroe.